# Global style overrides specific compoment style

Tags: css, actionscript-3, flex4

I have the following problem. I have a flex 4.1 project with a css file that contain following components:

```
global {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-anti-alias-type: advanced;
    modal-transparency-color:000000;
    focusColor: #b3001e;
    errorColor: #b3001e; }
```

and then I have the specific  style for a text input:

```
s|TextInput, s|NumericStepper, astra|IPv4AddressInput {
    color: #000000;
    disabledColor: #555;
    contentBackgroundColor: #e5e5e8;
    borderColor: #000000; }
```

but sometimes it happens that the s:textInput has a problem. the color of the characters you enter have sometimes the color of the Global style.
so you expected a black colored font but you see a white color font.

does anyone have a idea how to solve this or explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can force it to override using:

```
color: #000000 !important;
```